# How to plot a vector array having symbolic variables?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, dsolve

**I want to plot an array vector having symbolic variables in it. But I am getting an error which is given below.

??? Error using ==> plot
Conversion to double from sym is not possible.

Error in ==> dsolvenew at 36
plot(t2,qn2) **

The code is given below.

```
syms A Epsilon0 k1 k2 e s d R s f T c0 v0 v 
An        = 0.5*10^(-9);
Epsilon0n = 8.85*10^-12;
k1n       = 10;
k2n       = 10;
en        = 1.6*10^-19;
sn        = 1.8*10^(-9);%m gap size%
dn        = 3*sn; % total distance
Rn        = 1;
c0n=(An*Epsilon0n*k1n)/dn; 
t1=0:0.1:5;
fn=1000;
v0n=7.5;
Tn=5/f;
vn=v0n*sin(2*3.14*fn*t1);
plot(t1,vn); 
inits = 'q(0)=(20*10^(-20)),Q(0)=0';
[q,Q] = dsolve('Dq=((v/R)-(1/R)*(((d*q)+(s*Q))/(c0*d)))','DQ=   (((q+Q)/(A*Epsilon0*k1))*s)',inits);
qn1=vpa(subs(q,{A,Epsilon0,k1,k2,e,s,d,R,c0},  {An,Epsilon0n,k1n,k2n,en,sn,dn,Rn,c0n}),3);
i=1;
while i<length(t1);
qn2(i)=subs(qn1, v, vn(i));
i=i+1;
end
t2=t1(1:50);
plot(t2,qn2)
```

Comment: So with vector of symbols, are we talking about a vector valued function of symbolic variables?

Comment: @patrik..I just uploaded the code. I want to plot a vector " qn2 " vs time " t2 "...Thanks alot

Comment: So basically do a 2D plot over t and v? Is that what you want?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using symbolic math for this instead of solving it numerically (with `ode45` for example).

Comment: Numerical computation is ok too.. Can you  help me in solving this problem using ode45 ? @horchler

Comment: @patrik..Just one D Plot of the vector array "qn2" over time vector "t2"..